# Which set of rotation matrices describes an object's orientation in ECEF coordinate frame?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, coordinate-systems, rotational-kinematics, rotation

I'm trying to calculate what's known as the Angle of Attack (**AOA**) for a missile given some missile data. it would be more of a theoretical value for the **AOA** since I don't have any wind data. I posted a similar question at the aviation stack exchange, but I think my question has evolved into more of a coordinate system conventions question. I also use the term "aircraft" and "missile" interchangeably below because most of the references use the term "aircraft" whereas my data is for a missile.

I have some missile data that I want to use to calculate this **AOA** value. From what I understand the **AOA** is just the angle between the aircraft's forward unit vector (out the nose vector) and the x-component of the velocity vector (vx), as long as both vectors are in the same coordinate frame and assuming no wind.

[image]

My plan was to find the missile's forward unit vectors in the same manner as the "first answer" linked below but using the psi/theta/phi values in place of the yaw/pitch/roll values. Then find the angle between that forward unit vector and the x-component of the missile's velocity vector (vx) given in the data, using the dot product.

All of my data is in the [ECEF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECEF) frame and the data consists of the position (x,y,z), velocity components (vx,vy,vz), and the orientation components (psi, theta, phi).

There are two stack exchange answers that I think are on the right track, but they are not using the ECEF frame.

In the first answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/1568687/12131175 the unit vectors of the aircraft can be found using the rotation matrices, but I think they are using the NED coordinate frame and not ECEF.

In the second answer, https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/67213/52074 the **AOA** is found using the arctan function, but the vectors are in the aircraft's body frame.

So, my questions are:

1. Would this be the right way to calculate the **AOA**?
2. Is there a certain set of rotation matrices I should use to find those unit vectors the same way they were found in the first answer above, considering my orientation data is given in the ECEF frame (psi, theta, phi), and not the North-East-Down ([NED](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_tangent_plane_coordinates)) frame?

Thanks in advance!